# Opengl ES 3.0 iOS main loop

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I have to don't use GLKit. Main part of my project is written in c++ and another part in Objective-C just to create EAGLContext and set up main view, which I use to draw in.

For now, I got main screen and some geometric primitive on it. All of them draw like this (not in loop, just once):

```
Meteorite *met1 = new Meteorite();

aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
glVertexAttribPointer(aPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, met2->poly_coords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, met1->polygon_points+2);
```

So, I got three problems:
1. What if i got two objects to draw? Am i have to do like this?:

```
Meteorite *met1 = new Meteorite();
Meteorite *met2 = new Meteorite();

GLuint aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
glVertexAttribPointer(aPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, met1->poly_coords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, met1->polygon_points+2);

aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
glVertexAttribPointer(aPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, met2->poly_coords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, met2->polygon_points+2);
```

2. How can i move this objects separated?
3. I'm trying to figure out **how can i create the "main loop"** or something like this to redraw my objects, maybe to delete them, etc.

In OpenGL you can just create for e.g. while(1) loop and draw in this loop.

**UPDATE:**Alright, if 1 is ok then i resolved second problem by adding vec4 Translate parameter into my VertexShader.vsh, so i can move my objects separately. 
Still having third problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS has a class called [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html), which fills the same role that you might have used vertical retrace for on a classic CRT. You can use it as a hook to know when to redraw your view. If you do so then your redraws will occur at the screen's refresh rate.

You should never busy wait. It is power inefficient. You should therefore definitely never busy wait on mobile. Mobile phones are already considered to have an inadequate battery life, even when running efficiently.

If you absolutely can't switch to a modern callback-oriented approach then contexts aren't thread safe on iOS but you can put multiple contexts into a share group and share named GL resources between them. So you could run your code on a background thread, with a locking mechanism to tie it into the display link, render-to-texture and then just write a thin shim on the main thread that syncs the contexts and pushes the rendered scene to the relevant layer.

Comment: Ok, now i have displayLink method redraw. But if i put in this method my code for drawing (in question), nothing happens. 
Objects are ok, but they aren't draw.So how am I have to tell Opengl to redraw screen?

Comment: The exact same way you were already presenting it. `EAGLContext -presentRenderBuffer:`.